# Augmented reality -Pro Augmented Reality" by Raghav Sood-Chapter 8

Tags: android, augmented-reality, andar

My name is Cristina and i am studying telecommunications engineering in the last year.
My questions: i have tried the code from chapter 8 (named:A 3D Augmented Reality Model Viewer)from the book: **"Pro Augmented Reality" by Raghav Sood** on my phone,and everything goes ok with the models from there,but when i try to load my own models i get nothing.
I did my models in blender,then export them as .obj files,when i export them i checked the Triangle and Normals.I also tried with other models from the internet,but the models didn't load.
I studyed a lot the explications from this site http://code.google.com/p/andar/ about the andar code but still have no answer why my models aren't loading .
Please help me with an answer!

Answer (score 1):

1) You should probably check the size of your model, maybe the model is too big or too small and just not visible.

2) Another important element to check is the origin of your 3D model. For marker-based AR, the best solution is to define the origin at the ground plane of your model (from a side view, at the lowest vertical coordinate) and not in the center.

To check your model, I will advice you to load both your model and a model working with AndAR (e.g. plant.obj, sofa.obj) in Blender (File>>Append) and see if both are "roughly" aligned in Blender. If not you can align your model with the AndAR one (scale, origin), delete the AndAR mesh and export again.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer.Unfortunately it did not work as you have advised me.So, I thought of another solution, namely: to delete the models that are in the  **assets** folder and to put there others that I've created(by models i mean: the .obj and .mtl files),but even in this way it does't work.I want to mention that for this i  also modified  java class: ModelViewer.java in the area where apears the name of the models (eg. if originally i had ( "plant.obj" ,"chair.obj" etc.i changed with the name of my models).

Comment: So, I would like to ask you: why can't I delete the  .obj and .mtl files that come with the app, and add others in their place, or at least why I can't delete some of them, without the application crashes.  I've tried many variations: for example to let only one model and to delete the rest, but still not working.It is possible to be a probleme with some code in the java files?(I am a beginner in java and  I could not solve the problem if it is there).Thank you once again,and i will wait for answer if it is possible:)